# Need help with "Incorrect syntax near keyword GROUP"

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, union, case

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I keep getting incorrect syntax error, it seems like I correct one, then the next line popup. Right now I am getting a "Incorrect syntax near keyword GROUP. I have had a couple of version of my issues on this site. I really appreciate the help so far. I just need that boost to get this report working. Anyone know of any good classes in Minnesota for sql. The books cover the basics, I need the complex  sql class.

```
SELECT fgc, sum(Totpay) as Totpay, Sum(TotChg) as TotChg
from
(                     
    SELECT fgc, sum(pay) as TotPay, 0 as TotChg
    from 
    (
        SELECT fgc, pay,
               CASE 
                   WHEN  [date]<= 30 THEN 'pmt 0-30'      
                   WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'pmt 30-60'
                   WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'pmt 61-90'
                   WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'pmt 91-120'
                   WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'pmt 121-150'
                   WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'pmt 151-180'
                   ELSE 'pmt 181+' 
               END
        FROM @Pay 
        GROUP BY fgc

        UNION

        SELECT fgc, 0 as TotPay, sum(chg) as TotChg
        from
        (
            SELECT fgc, chg,
                   CASE 
                       WHEN [date]<= 30 THEN 'charge 0-30'      
                       WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'charge 30-60' 
                       WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'charge 61-90'
                       WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'charge 91-120'
                       WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'charge 121-150'
                       WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'charge 151-180'
                       ELSE 'charge 181+' 
                   END
            FROM @Chg
        )
        GROUP BY fgc 
    )
    GROUP BY fgc
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. It should now be apparent what your problem is. My guess is that it's improperly placed parenthesis.

Comment: @Gabe: While I agree with *kaps*'s answer, your point is valid too. I think you should make it an answer. It is obvious now that the left part of UNION should probably follow the pattern of the right part, while it doesn't.

Comment: Big props to the peopled who salvaged this question into something worth answering. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using alias for inline queries. Following not giving me any syntax error.

```
        SELECT fgc, sum(Totpay) as Totpay, Sum(TotChg) as TotChg
        from
        (                     
        SELECT fgc, sum(pay) as TotPay, 0 as TotChg
        from 
            (SELECT fgc, pay,
                CASE 
                WHEN  [date]<= 30 THEN 'pmt 0-30'      
                WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'pmt 30-60'
                WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'pmt 61-90'
                WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'pmt 91-120'
                WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'pmt 121-150'
                WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'pmt 151-180'
                ELSE 'pmt 181+' 
                END
            FROM @Pay 
            GROUP BY fgc 

            UNION

            SELECT fgc, 0 as TotPay, sum(chg) as TotChg
            from
                (SELECT fgc, chg,
                    CASE 
                    WHEN [date]<= 30 THEN 'charge 0-30'      
                    WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'charge 30-60' 
                    WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'charge 61-90'
                    WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'charge 91-120'
                    WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'charge 121-150'
                    WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'charge 151-180'
                    ELSE 'charge 181+' 
                    END
                 FROM @Chg) as innerTable2
             GROUP BY fgc 
            ) As innertable1
        GROUP BY fgc
    )  as outerTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, GROUP BY keyword is used in case using aggregate function, and in order to use it, you must group all column with out using aggregate function on it.

For e.g.: instead GROUP BY fgc, should use GROUP BY (fgc, pay, aliasName).

Change:

SELECT fgc, pay,
                CASE 
                WHEN  [date]<= 30 THEN 'pmt 0-30'
                WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'pmt 30-60'
                WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'pmt 61-90'
                WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'pmt 91-120'
                WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'pmt 121-150'
                WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'pmt 151-180'
                ELSE 'pmt 181+' 
                END
            FROM @Pay 
            GROUP BY fgc

into

SELECT fgc, pay,
                CASE 
                WHEN  [date]<= 30 THEN 'pmt 0-30'
                WHEN [date]> 30 AND [date] <= 60 THEN 'pmt 30-60'
                WHEN [date]> 61 AND [date] <= 90 THEN 'pmt 61-90'
                WHEN [date]> 91 AND [date] <= 120 THEN 'pmt 91-120'
                WHEN [date]> 121 AND [date] <= 150 THEN 'pmt 121-150'
                WHEN [date]> 151 AND [date] <= 180 THEN 'pmt 151-180'
                ELSE 'pmt 181+' 
                END as alias
            FROM @Pay 
            GROUP BY (fgc, pay, alias)

Hope this help.

P/S: tks  Gabe for correcting me.

Comment: -1; You're wrong about `TotPay`. It's not a column he's selecting, it's a constant!